# Loading multiple build scripts (DRY) using Jenkins Workflow plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I've been playing around with the Jenkins Workflow plugin but I'm unsure about best practise for more complex builds. Primarily:

> Is there a way to load a groovy script from inside another groovy script (when not using the DSL text area option)?

I think the answer is no, but I wanted to ask anyway.

My obvious motivation is to share common code (e.g. cloning, installing RPM's, deploying etc.). My use-case is the building and deploying of microservices across various AWS environments so we have a lot of Jenkins jobs (and a lot of repeated steps).

The current 'workaround' I have in place is to use the DSL text area to load multiple scripts:

```
def repo = 'example-sensu-rspec-tests'

node {   
    git url: 'https://github.com/bsnape/jenkins-workflow-example.git'
    common = load 'common.groovy'
    flow = load 'flow2.groovy'

    common.clone(repo)   

    flow.unit()
    flow.acceptance()

    common.deploy('staging')
}
```

`common` refers to generic things, whereas `flow` would be project-specific build steps.

Is this a reasonable approach (obviously this is a basic example)?

I know that Jenkins also provides the [Workflow Global Library](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/cps-global-lib/README.md) but I'm not sure about the current implementation (i.e. Jenkins having an internal Git repository).

Can this repository be configured to point to or sync with an external repository (e.g. hosted on GitHub)? Otherwise, I'm not sure how usable this feature is (please let me know if you disagree).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to load a groovy script from inside another groovy script

Sure, using the `load` step. Perhaps you should clarify your question.

> Can [the `cps-global-lib`] repository be configured to point to or sync with an external repository

Sorry, no.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot use jenkins as our SCM, so we have a trick:

1. We store the entire **workflowLibs** in Bitbucket.
2. We have a jenkins job that gets kicked off when the Bitbucket repo gets udpated.
3. That jenkins job checks out workflowLibs.git from Jenkins AND from Bitbucket.
4. It then rm -rf everything in Jenkins, copies the latest from Bitbucket and does a "git commit && git push" and voila jenkins **workflowLibs** is updated from bitbucket!

Comment: Yes, you can do this to synchronize from a non-Git repository. From a Git repository hosted elsewhere, it is a bit simpler: just `fetch` and `push`.

Comment: Do you have the Jenkins SSH credentials being used? Can you elaborate as to how your configuration for pushing to Jenkins is?

Comment: I honestly don't remember how I did it, but basically I had to give the slave instance git access to both those repos.  I almost think I had to follow the instructions on this page to make it work: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin